# Why isn't this list working... "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to Python and am doing an intro project. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working/how to fix it. Basically, the user gives a list of words, and if the word isn't plural, it is supposed to add an "s". But this isn't working... here's the code. I appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you so much.

```
def pluralize_words():

#########################################################
#Checks if words in plural_words are indeed plural and corrects them if not##
#########################################################

    global singular_words
    global plural_words

    for i in plural_words:
        if plural_words[i].endswith("s"):
            word_is_plural = True
        else:
            word_is_plural = False
            plural_words[i] = word + "s"

    print(plural_words)
```

Comment: Where does the variable `word` come from in your example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a good spot for list comprehension, we can use `endswith('s')` to do our evaultions

```
words = ['sings', 'dance', 'runs', 'hides']

plural = [i if i.endswith('s') else i + 's' for i in words]
```

> ```
> chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/9.22$ python3.7 uk.py
> ['sings', 'dances', 'runs', 'hides']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Stephen and U9 each gave great solutions. I will explain why your code did not work. Notice that plural_words is a list of strings. Therefore, when you call `for i in plural_words:`, you are iterating over the words in that list, and thus each iteration you get the string itself (and not a number). For example:

Input:

```
plural_words = ['bark','dog','cats']
for i in plural_words:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
bark
dog
cats
```

Since each iteration you're setting your i as a string from your list, it does not make sense to call an item of the list using that string as an index (as lists can only have integer indices). If I ran your code above using my example plural_words list, the first iteration I would be calling is plural_words['bark'], which would give me the specific error that you just received. To circumvent this problem, you can use enumerate as mentioned by U9, or you can iterate over the range of the length of your list (so i would be a number). Here is an example:

Input:

```
plural_words = ['bark','dog','cats']
for i in range(len(plural_words)):
    print('i:', i)
    print('word:', plural_words[i])
```

Output:

```
i: 0
word: bark
i: 1
word: dog
i: 2
word: cats
```

In this case the `len(plural_words)` is 3, so you are actually running `for i in range(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Need `enumerate`:

```
def pluralize_words():
    global singular_words
    global plural_words

    for idx,i in enumerate(plural_words):
        if i.endswith("s"):
            word_is_plural = True
        else:
            word_is_plural = False
            plural_words[idx] = i + "s"

    print(plural_words)
```

Better is:

```
plural_words=[i if i[-1]!='s' else i+'s' for i in plural_words]
```

Or:

```
plural_words=list(map(lambda x: x+'s' if x[-1]!='s' else x,plural_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `plural_words` is a list of words, then `i` is a word (not an integer; the variable name `i` is usually used with integers in while loops; in Python, for loops don't usually have a counter variable, but they'll give you the list item itself every iteration, rather than the element number). You should be checking if `i` ends with s (not whether `plural_words[i]` ends with s).

To fix the code you could do something like this (and although it's not the most efficient or best method, it should demonstrate why your code isn't working, and what you would need to do for it to work with your methodology):

```
def pluralize_words():
    global singular_words
    global plural_word

    i=0
    for word in plural_words:
        if word.endswith("s"):
            word_is_plural = True
        else:
            word_is_plural = False
            plural_words[i] = word + "s"
        i+=1

    print(plural_words)
```